# Compare two separate data set quantities in Excel

Tags: excel, comparison

I have been trying to compare two separate data sets to determine how many products have been delivered from the expected product inventory.

- The left data set (A:B) will be the expected products and their quantities.
- The right data set (D:E) will be the current delivered stock.

The check should be able to check how many items are outstanding to be delivered.

I tried concatenating the columns i.e =CONCATENATE(A:A,",",B:B) and =CONCATENATE(D:D,",",E:E) so that each row was something like Cuff-MIN-LH,9

Then I performed a VLOOKUP, =VLOOKUP(C2,G:G,1,FALSE) to see which concatenated stings matched. Screenshot below.

[image]

Comment: Start with a basic lookup to find the ordered quantity - not sure what you're saying when you mention concatenation?  If you tried a formula, the best way to get answers here is to show what you tried.

Comment: Thanks @TimWilliams I updated more about what I tried and a screenshot of the Concatenations and VLOOKUP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For example:

[image]

I have the original quantity in a "helper" column to keep the other formula simpler...
If you really want you can combine them.